# Expected result in one Column without nulls

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

want to get the output in single column from multiple columns. Please check the below example for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
={QUERY(FLATTEN(A1:G), "where Col1 is not null skipping 2"),
  QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(A1:G), "where Col1 is not null offset 1"), "skipping 2")}
```

[image]